# HowTo enforce SHA512 in Outlook 2010 (and above) for S/Mime?

Tags: group-policy, outlook, outlook-2010

When you setup S/Mime in Outlook 2010 you can also choose the hash algorithm as seen here:

[image]

Can we control that via GPO? I would like to disable all the other options if possible.